nextJS suddenly cannot resolve components
I'm building a website in NextJS and it was working well until today when it started saying that it's unable to resolve multiple elements:

Some things that I tried that didnt work:

Get rid of the type alias and use the normal path name for each element
run npm install in the /app directory as suggested under another post
delete the .next directory and run npm run build

Here's what my folder structure looks like and the import alias:
[2



I'm using the /src directory along with javascript

have you installed any plugins to vs code recently or updated any config like package.json?

No, the only thing I did was install another npm package but i removed it because it didn't work

did you also remove the node_modules folder ?

no, only the .next folder

Solution for my problem was to duplicate the project and select 'no' on the use /src directory prompt while initialising the project. Couldn't find anything else anywhere
